# .Net Webbrowser control not working for https web api call

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, desktop-application

We are facing issues with .net Web browser control (.Net v 4.0)

Web app fails with status 0 when it makes a call (options) to Web API which is protected with SSL. If we remove SSL it is working fine.

Below is the code which is failing

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        "authorization": 'bearer ' + sessionStorage.token
    }
});

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType:'json',
    async: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    error: function (err) {
        debugger;
        if (err.status != 404) {
            console.log(err);
            alert(err.statusText);
        }
    },
    success: success
});
```